# Как найти файл, имя которого содержит дату создания (к примеру, 25112014.log) равную текущей дате и скопировать его?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Есть папка с ежедневными лог-файлами. Как реализовать запуск копирование созданного в текущем дне файла по крону?

Comment: отредактируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, придав ему более очевидную, понятную форму

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен, но думаю мой ответ даст нужную информацию)

Answer (score 1):

В linux есть команда `touch`. Информацию по ней можно получить через `man touch`.

Я предлагаю для решения задачи использовать именно её. При выполнении `touch access.log` дата создания файла будет текущей, но можно указать и 'свою':

```
touch --date="2015-05-27 01:02:03" access.log
```

Для крона можно всё записать в одну строку:

```
* * * * * mv /path/to/log-file /path/to/backup-dir && touch --date="2015-05-27 01:02:03" /path/to/log-file
```

Пример будет выполняться каждую минуту и перемещать лог-файл `log-file` из каталога `/path/to/` в каталог `/path/to/backup-dir`, а на его месте создастся файл `log-file` с датой `2015-05-27 01:02:03`

Comment: Вроде надо было сохранить дату, а не задать фиксированную? UPDATE: Нет, я не так вопрос понял. Хотя, кажется, всё равно не то...

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем. Разобрался.
можно так

```
cp \`date "+%d.%m.%y.log"\` /tmp/
```

или так

```
cp \`ls -t *.log | head -1\` /tmp/
```

Comment: Вообще-то очень сложно было понять по вопросу, что именно это вам нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Копирует файлы, который были созданы/изменялись сегодня из `<src/dir/>` в `<dst/dir/>`. Если я правильно понял вопрос.

```
find <src/dir/> -maxdepth 1 -type f -daystart -mtime -1 -exec cp {} < <dst/dir/>\
```